# How to assign additional public IP's to private addresses

Tags: networking, ip

I'm looking for some guidance on accessing private clients behind my Access Point p2p link using public ip addresses.

The master end of my P2P link connects to the internet via its WAN port; its assigned a specific IP address. I have additional public IP's available for use that I would like to assign to client on the LAN side essentially mapping a specific public ip in my subnet to that unique private ip.

Can you tell me if this is possible and how this is done? Thank you for your help.

Found a link : [How to assign a Public IP address to a home pc on a home network](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/wireless-networks/55686-how-assign-public-ip-address-home-pc-home-network.html)
Is this correct to do in this way?

Comment: use portforwarding

Comment: Thanks buddy. Could you please give some hints on how to set the portforwarding in this case?

Comment: Is it to set the port forwards under Firewall section? My supplier AP got it.